# Numpy cumsum considering NaNs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, cumsum

I am looking for a succinct way to go from:

```
 a = numpy.array([1,4,1,numpy.nan,2,numpy.nan])
```

to:

```
  b = numpy.array([1,5,6,numpy.nan,8,numpy.nan])
```

The best I can do currently is:

```
b = numpy.insert(numpy.cumsum(a[numpy.isfinite(a)]), (numpy.argwhere(numpy.isnan(a)) - numpy.arange(len(numpy.argwhere(numpy.isnan(a))))), numpy.nan)
```

Is there a shorter way to accomplish the same? What about doing a cumsum along an axis of a 2D array?

Comment: numpy has a `nancumsum` function added in version 1.12.0. It does not quite do what you want directly though since it would give you the result `[1, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about (for not-too-big arrays):

```
In [34]: import numpy as np

In [35]: a = np.array([1,4,1,np.nan,2,np.nan])

In [36]: a*0 + np.nan_to_num(a).cumsum()
Out[36]: array([  1.,   5.,   6.,  nan,   8.,  nan])
```

Answer (score 8):

[`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is a library build on top of `numpy`. It's
[`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series) class has a `cumsum` method, which preserves the `nan`'s and is considerably faster than the solution proposed by DSM:

```
In [15]: a = arange(10000.0)

In [16]: a[1] = np.nan

In [17]: %timeit a*0 + np.nan_to_num(a).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 465 us per loop

In [18] s = pd.Series(a)

In [19]: s.cumsum()
Out[19]: 
0       0
1     NaN
2       2
3       5
...
9996    49965005
9997    49975002
9998    49985000
9999    49994999
Length: 10000

In [20]: %timeit s.cumsum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 175 us per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

[Masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#the-numpy-ma-module) are for just this type of situation.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy import ma
>>> a = np.array([1,4,1,np.nan,2,np.nan])
>>> b = ma.masked_array(a,mask = (np.isnan(a) | np.isinf(a)))
>>> b
masked_array(data = [1.0 4.0 1.0 -- 2.0 --],
         mask = [False False False  True False  True],
   fill_value = 1e+20)
>>> c = b.cumsum()
>>> c
masked_array(data = [1.0 5.0 6.0 -- 8.0 --],
         mask = [False False False  True False  True],
   fill_value = 1e+20)
>>> c.filled(np.nan)
array([  1.,   5.,   6.,  nan,   8.,  nan])
```